# Quarkus Panache OneToMany relation is not persisted in database

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm currently tinkering with a simple HTTP resource. My model consists of "trees" with multiple "fruits". Both inherit from PanacheEntity.

Tree:

```
    @Entity
    public class Tree extends PanacheEntity {
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tree", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Fruit

```
    @Entity
    public class Fruit extends PanacheEntity {

    public String name;
    public String color;
    public int cores;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonbTransient
    public Tree tree;
    }
```

Resource:

```
    import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.rest.data.panache.PanacheEntityResource;

    public interface TreeResource extends PanacheEntityResource<Tree, Long> { }
```

This is my POST request that I send via Swagger

```
{
  "name": "Apple Tree",
  "fruits": [
    {
      "color": "green",
      "cores": 3,
      "name": "Apple2"
    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "cores": 4,
      "name": "Apple"
    }
  ]
}
```

The response tells me, that Ids were created for all objects:

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "fruits": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "color": "green",
      "cores": 3,
      "name": "Apple2"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "color": "red",
      "cores": 4,
      "name": "Apple"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Apple Tree"
}
```

BUT when I call the Get all under /trees I get the following response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "fruits": [],
    "name": "Oak"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "fruits": [],
    "name": "Apple Tree"
  }
]
```

Fruits are always empty. Checking the postgres database reveals that all "tree_id" columns in Fruit are null. I'm pretty sure this is a beginners problem but after checking multiple samples I just cannot find what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Could you prepare a self contained test case (a simple Maven project reproducing the issue) and post it in the Quarkus tracker? I think we need to have a look to this use case (and Panache REST Resource is fairly new so feedback is very welcome).

Comment: Sure I will create a small project over the weekend. In the meantime I resolved the issue by just declaring "OneToMany" but not the other way "ManyToOne" so now it's unidirectional.

Comment: So I was just about to finish up my sample project and decided to try it again and now it's working fine at least after the initial POST. I then tried to update my data via PUT and now I'm again seeing the same issue. Link to my sample project (based on quarkus official panache-quickstart): https://github.com/WeinbM/quarkus-hibernate-orm-sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by setting parent objects to children.
I had Job and JobArgs items to persist.

```java
    // ... somewhere in JobArg.java
    @JsonbTransient
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "job_id_fk"))
    public Job job;
```

```java
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "job", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<JobArg> arguments = new ArrayList<>();
    // ... somewhere in Job.java 
    // I used reactive-pgclient so my method return Uni<T>
    public void addArgument(final JobArg jobArg) {
        arguments.add(jobArg);
        jobArg.job = this;
    }
    public static Uni<Job> insert(final UUID userId, final JobDto newJob) {
        final Job job = new Job();
        //... map fields from dto ...
        newJob.getArguments().stream().map(arg -> {
            final JobArg jobArg = new JobArg();
            //... map fields from dto ...
            return jobArg;
        }).forEach(job::addArgument);
        
        final Uni<Void> jobInsert = job.persist();
        final Uni<UserAction> userActionInsert = UserAction.insertAction(type, job.id, userId, null);
        return Uni.combine().all().unis(jobInsert, userActionInsert).combinedWith(result -> job);
    }
```

This is an example code from [Vlad Mihalcea's blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/):
For bidirectional mappings:

```java
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "post",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
 
    //Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity
 
    public void addComment(PostComment comment) {
        comments.add(comment);
        comment.setPost(this);
    }
 
    public void removeComment(PostComment comment) {
        comments.remove(comment);
        comment.setPost(null);
    }
}
 
@Entity(name = "PostComment")
@Table(name = "post_comment")
public class PostComment {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String review;
 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Post post;
 
    //Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity
 
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof PostComment )) return false;
        return id != null && id.equals(((PostComment) o).getId());
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
}
```

> There are several things to note on the aforementioned mapping:
>
> The @ManyToOne association uses FetchType.LAZY because, otherwise, we’d fall back to EAGER fetching which is bad for performance.
>
> The parent entity, Post, features two utility methods (e.g. addComment and removeComment) which are used to synchronize both sides
> of the bidirectional association. You should always provide these
> methods whenever you are working with a bidirectional association as,
> otherwise, you risk very subtle state propagation issues.
>
> The child entity, PostComment, implement the equals and hashCode methods. Since we cannot rely on a natural identifier for equality
> checks, we need to use the entity identifier instead for the equals
> method. However, you need to do it properly so that equality is
> consistent across all entity state transitions, which is also the
> reason why the hashCode has to be a constant value. Because we rely on
> equality for the removeComment, it’s good practice to override equals
> and hashCode for the child entity in a bidirectional association

.